# What a different between switch and if while looping form on theme options

Tags: wordpress, themes

I want to know what is good practice for loop a form option in theme options.

Example I found some of coders use switch

```
switch $value['type']
case 'text':
...
break;
case 'select':
...
break;
case 'textarea':
...
break;
case "radio":
...
break;
case "checkbox":
...
break;
```

also some of them use IF

```
if $value['type'] = text
...
else if $value['type'] = select
...
else if $value['type'] = textarea
...
else if $value['type'] = radio
...
else if $value['type'] = checkbox
...
else
```

What a different between these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is of a general programming nature, e.g. how to write PHP and not related to theme options strictly spoken.

So unless you don't provide any wordpress related information why you ask that, I think a little read of the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) is good for a starter - next to doing some [basic googling](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=se&ie=UTF-8&q=php+if+switch).

Answer (score 0):

It basically boils down to readability; Switches are easier to read than a bunch of else if's.